# send and grab data with php curl

Tags: php, curl, post

i try to send data with this code (in page named send.php)

```
$data = array("name" => "Reda", "age" => "36");  
$post = http_build_query($data);                                                                  


$ch = curl_init('http://127.0.0.1/testcurl.php');                                                                      

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);                                                                  

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                                                             

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($response);
```

and grab it with this code (in page named testcurl.php):

```
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {

print_r($_POST['name']);

}
```

but i get nothing or an empty array like this array ()
can any one help me please

Comment: I'm assuming in your 2nd block of code you mean `$_POST` instead of `$_post`? You should start by fixing that.

Comment: yes you are right but that is not the problem i still get nothing

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your code where you're capturing or dumping the response. Try changing `curl_exec($ch);` to `var_dump(curl_exec($ch));` to see if you're getting any response.

Comment: i got this in the first page : string(3) " "

Comment: Is that 2nd block what's inside the testcurl.php file? If so, there's probably more code in that file causing this issue. Can you post that?

Comment: in the page named testcurl.php there is nothing but the 2nd block

Comment: Can you comment that block and add `echo 'hello';` to that file. Then confirm you see `string(5) "hello"` on the first page?

Comment: I got this : string(8) "hello "

Comment: Good. In testcurl.php, simply try `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: in the page where the 1st block i got: string(77) "array(2) { ["name"]=> string(4) "Reda" ["age"]=> string(2) "36" } " , in testcurl.php i got: array(0) { }

Comment: It looks like the code is working fine now... You can now use the variables `$_POST['name']` and `$_POST['age']` in testcurl.php. Doesn't that solve your original problem?

Comment: No i still get a blank page

Comment: I see your edited comment now... That's a separate HTTP request, so the POST data will not be persisted between the first request and second request. That's how the HTTP protocol works, it's stateless by nature. To persist the data, you're going to need more code. It could be a cookie-based session, a database engine, a simple text file, etc. Unfortunately that's beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow question, so I'm not sure I can help you anymore. Google and/or the PHP documentation will be able to help you get started.

Comment: I want to thank you very much sir, you've halped me alot .